# Can't download on Android studio 2.3

Tags: android

```
public class DowloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String result="";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        try{
            url=new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in =urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data=reader.read();
            while (data!=-1){
                char current=(char)data;
                result+=current;
                data=reader.read();
           }
           return result;
           }
         catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

There is something wrong with my Download Task?
I can't download although I add permission to the manifest.
I use `execute("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London").get();` on the `onCreate`

```
09-24 22:26:45.434 29533-29533/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system
09-24 22:26:45.434 29533-29533/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
09-24 22:26:45.435 29533-29533/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-24 22:26:45.653 29533-29533/com.example.inbal.wheather I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-24 22:26:45.703 29533-29533/com.example.inbal.wheather W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at com.example.inbal.wheather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:28)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at com.example.inbal.wheather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:20)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29561/com.example.inbal.wheather W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-24 22:26:45.843 29533-29533/com.example.inbal.wheather I/Message: Failed
09-24 22:26:45.855 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                            [ 09-24 22:26:45.950 29533:29533 D/         ]
                                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42e2830, tid 29533


                                                                            [ 09-24 22:26:45.951 29533:29533 W/         ]
                                                                            Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 
09-24 22:26:45.954 29533-29533/com.example.inbal.wheather D/Atlas: Validating map...
09-24 22:26:46.108 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-24 22:26:46.108 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-24 22:26:46.348 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaf434ca0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
09-24 22:26:46.362 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ca0: ver 2 0
09-24 22:26:46.383 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-24 22:26:46.450 29533-29562/com.example.inbal.wheather D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ca0: ver 2 0
09-24 22:26:46.660 29533-29541/com.example.inbal.wheather W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.441ms
09-24 22:26:46.692 29533-29533/com.example.inbal.wheather W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: do you get any error? if so what is that. the api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London link return error 401 in my browswer??!!!!

Comment: Please add the error to your question! If you get an exception, please add the complete stack trace..

Comment: In addition to the previous comment it seems the error is requiring you to obtain an API key since it says `Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.`